# Karma not able to start PhantomJS on Windows - Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am completely lost about this "UNKNOWN" error:

**karma.conf.js:**

```
frameworks: ['mocha', 'should'],

plugins: ['karma-mocha',
          'karma-should',              
          'karma-phantomjs-launcher'],

...
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
```

**Error:**

```
23 07 2015 14:35:37.691:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
23 07 2015 14:35:37.701:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
23 07 2015 14:35:37.707:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
23 07 2015 14:35:37.738:ERROR [karma]: { [Error: spawn UNKNOWN] code: 'UNKNOWN', errno: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'spawn' }
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:749:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1093:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:933:9)
    at Object._execCommand (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:63:21)
    at Object._start (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\index.js:72:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:14:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Object.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at Object.start (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\base.js:41:10)
    at C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launcher.js:88:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at launch (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launcher.js:40:11)
    at invoke (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JINGA4X\git\mdl-sample-project\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:161:24)
    at Server.g (events.js:257:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
```

I installed PhantomJS with `npm install -g phantomjs`, getting this output:

```
Looks like an `npm install -g` on windows; unable to check for already installed version.
Download already available at C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip
Extracting zip contents
Removing C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
Copying extracted folder C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1437719855881\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows -> C:
\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe
C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules\which
```

Before launching the test I tried executing the file shown below, with the same result:

```
C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

The user profile running node:

```
Users\JINGA4X
```

Does not match the user profile running phantom:

```
Users\MYUSER
```

So install phantom manually:

- https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip
- Unzip the executable to C:\Users\JINGA4X\phantomjs
- Set the path via powershell:

  ```
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $env:Path + ";C:\Users\JINGA4X\phantomjs", 'User')
  ```

**References**

- [FAQ: Where Do I Save Files, and How Exactly Do I Do That?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2011/10/02/10216395.aspx)
- [Explore Your [Environment]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/13/explore-your-environment.aspx)
- [Create UserProfiles and Properties using powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh1/archive/2012/02/25/create-userprofiles-and-properties-using-powershell.aspx)
- [Unit testing your web application through Intern - Part 1 - Mobile Cloud Services Blog - Mobile Cloud Services](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/22cf1469-02c7-44ff-a70e-fc5aeda3d4e8/entry/unit_testing_your_web_application_through_intern?lang=en)